# Simple Index-Calculation based on column-mean in R

Tags: python, r, dataframe, indexing, statistics

I have a dataframe with around 10 columns. All are of type numeric and indicating a different geographic region. Some are relative values, like percentage of inhabitants with a certain degree, others are total values like the total population. It loos more or less like this:

```
median_age bachelor_rate  emp_rate                       
1       35.2    0.05223252 0.6185185 
2       22.5    0.40045249 0.7744094 
3       36.3    0.26750261 0.8210526 
4       36.8    0.07753825 0.5801861 
5       29.9    0.04805492 0.3593074 
6       26.8    0.00000000 0.4762367 
>
```

What I wanted to do is to calculate an "index" for each column. I thought I'd take the mean of each columns and than calculate the difference to the mean for each cell value. 
E.G for the first cell of the `median_age-column`:

```
mean_age = mean(df$mean_age)
median_age_1 = df$median_age[1]
index = median_age_1/mean_age
```

Besides all mathematical and index-related questions. How could I write a function that does this for all columns and all cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose to use R, I think, the following is one way to go. What mutate_all() does is to loop through all columns and do exact the same job. So you want to think that `.` becomes each column name while R is looping through the data. For each column, you can find an average value with `mean()`. Since you want to divide each values in each column by its mean value, you can express the idea as `~./mean(.)`. Since I added a name to this function. R created three new columns. If you want to overwrite your original columns, you can do the following: `mutate_all(mydf, .funs = list(~./mean(.)))`.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate_all(mydf, .funs = list(index = ~./mean(.)))

  median_age bachelor_rate  emp_rate median_age_index bachelor_rate_index emp_rate_index
1       35.2    0.05223252 0.6185185           1.1264           0.3705394      1.0224261
2       22.5    0.40045249 0.7744094           0.7200           2.8408247      1.2801176
3       36.3    0.26750261 0.8210526           1.1616           1.8976733      1.3572199
4       36.8    0.07753825 0.5801861           1.1776           0.5500592      0.9590617
5       29.9    0.04805492 0.3593074           0.9568           0.3409034      0.5939439
6       26.8    0.00000000 0.4762367           0.8576           0.0000000      0.7872308
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(median_age = c(35.2, 22.5, 36.3, 36.8, 29.9, 26.8
), bachelor_rate = c(0.05223252, 0.40045249, 0.26750261, 0.07753825, 
0.04805492, 0), emp_rate = c(0.6185185, 0.7744094, 0.8210526, 
0.5801861, 0.3593074, 0.4762367)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Or in `base R` `mydf[paste0(names(mydf), "_index")] <- mydf/colMeans(mydf)[col(mydf)]`